# how to re-render a vue.js component when a variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component that load the data of books from the back-end and then put then into cards.

I wanted to allow the user to change the sorting of the books from default to by rating or the newest etc, so I declared a variable name `sorting` and set to default and add a drop-drown menu to change the variable sorting from default, and put the variable in the URL that get the data from the back end like in `get_books` method:

```
data(){
    return {
        audio_books:[],
        page:1,
        last_page:false,
        sorting:"default",
    }

},
methods: {
    get_books() {
        axios.get('load_all_audio_books/'+this.sorting+'?page='+this.page).then(response=> {
            $.each(response.data.data, (key, v) => {
                this.audio_books.push(v);
                if (response.data.current_page==response.data.last_page){
                    this.last_page=true;
                }

            });
        })
        this.page++;

    },
```

the back end :-
web.php

```
Route::get('/load_all_audio_books/{sort}',[\App\Http\Controllers\load_book::class,'get_all_audiobooks']);
```

the back-end function:-

```
public function get_all_audiobooks($sort)
{
    if($sort=="default")
    {
        $books=DB::table('audio_books')->paginate(10);
        return $books;
    }
    elseif ($sort=="rate")
    {
        $books=DB::table('audio_books')->orderBy('rating','desc')->paginate(10);
        return $books;
    }
    elseif ($sort=="newest")
    {
        $books=DB::table('audio_books')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
        return $books;
    }
    elseif ($sort=="oldest")
    {
        $books=DB::table('audio_books')->orderBy('rating')->paginate(10);
        return $books;
    }
```

now what I want is to re-render the component whenever the variable sorting change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform the sorting in the backend, you are half way there (I found the `page` part confusing so I temporarily removed it from my demo below).

1. Create a method that fires the HTTP call (Done per method `get_books`)
2. Create a watcher that listens for changes in the value of `sorting`.
3. Use the watcher to fire off the HTTP call again

```
<template>
<!-- Other stuff -->
<select v-model="sorting">
  <option value="prop1">Prop 1</option>
  <option value="prop2">Prop 2</option>
</select>
<!-- Other stuff -->
</template>

<script>
watch: {
  sorting(newVal, oldVal) {
    this.get_books(newVal)
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.get_books(this.sorting)
},
methods: {
  get_books(sort) {
        axios.get(`load_all_audio_books/${sort`).then(response=> {
            $.each(response.data.data, (key, v) => {
                this.audio_books.push(v);
                if (response.data.current_page==response.data.last_page){
                    this.last_page=true;
                }

            });
        })
    },
}
</script>
```

Watchers are one solution. You could do this in a multiple different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding these two line to the function that changes the value of the variable "sorting"

```
change_sort(sort)
    {
        this.page=1;
        this.sorting=sort;
        //the first line empty the audio_books array
        this.audio_books=[];
        //the second line call the function that get the data from the 
        //back end with the new sorting value then repopulate the 
       //audio_books array with the new values 
        this.get_books();
       

    }
```

Comment: Although your solution is correct, it isn't efficient. You are adding another method that you don't need to. 

Having said that, if it makes sense to you, then I would use it :)